# Have to use model name instead of field name when queriyng ManyToManyField from django model

Tags: python, django

I have the following model:

```py
class ShoppingList(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='Main')
    owners = models.ManyToManyField(User, through='ListOwner')


class ListOwner(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    shopping_list = models.ForeignKey(ShoppingList, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    is_main_owner = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Next, I'm trying to query `ShoppingList` for the current user.
I used this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships as an example.

I expected that right way to do it is to use this construction:

```py
@login_required
def index(request):
    shopping_list = ShoppingList.objects.filter(owners__user=request.user)\
        .order_by('id').first()
# something else
```

but in this case, I get an error: `Related Field got invalid lookup: user`

Everything works fine if use `listowner` instead of `owner` in `filter()` function like this:

```py
shopping_list = ShoppingList.objects.filter(listowner__user=request.user)\
        .order_by('id').first()
```

Can anybody please explain to me why the first one isn't working (while it is recommended to use it in Django documentation)?

Answer (score 0):

The reason it does not work is because the `ManyToManyField` refers to the `User` model, hence:

```
ShoppingList.objects.filter(owners=…)
```

expects a `User`, the lookup `__user` is invalid, since you are already filtering on a `user`, and the `User` model has no `user` field, or a relation named `user`.

You thus can filter with:

```
shopping_list = ShoppingList.objects.filter(
    owners=request.user
).order_by('id').first()
```

An alternative is to join on the *through* model yourself. You then first go through the relation to the `ListOwner` by using the `ForeignKey` relation in reverse. You do that by specifying the [**`related_query_name=…`** parameter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.related_query_name), which by default is the name of the model in lowercase. This is what you did in your second solution.

Comment: But the way you've suggested is the same as I tried at first time (second code snippet in the original question), isn't it?

Comment: @N.Verkhovin: no, it here says `owners=`, not `owners__user=`.